# C++ Debug Assertion Failed _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Tags: c++, c, debugging, assertion

I've looked through similar questions here, but still cannot realise, what am I doing wrong. Help, please.

I need to make template for string class with limited size (like in Pascal)
Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/syZf3yM8

Here's the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jo8i.png

Comment: To start with, build a debug version and run in the debugger. The debugger will stop at the location of the crash, and let you step up the function call stack to your code. There you will be able to examine values of variables.

Answer (score 0):

In my_string destructor,you code is:

```
~my_string () {
                delete [] this->text;
        }
```

you should not do this ,because text is array,not a pointer. when you call `*S3 = *S1 + *S2`,the  `my_string <max_size, T> operator+(const my_string& s)` is called. In this operator, the  `my_string <max_size, T> res` is local variable and in the stack. When this function is over, the res is automatically deleted. So assigning res to S3 is error. you can fixed like this:

```
~my_string () {

    }

my_string <max_size, T> operator+(const my_string& s) {
        my_string <max_size, T> res;
        int count = 0;
        while (this->get_char(count) != '\0') {
            res.set_char(this->get_char(count), count);
            count++;
        }

        for(int i = 0; count < max_size; i++){
            if (s.get_char(i) == '\0') { res.set_char('\0', count); break; }
            res.set_char(s.get_char(i), count);
            count++;
        }
        return res;
    }



my_string& operator=(const my_string& s){
        int size=s.get_length();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            this->set_char(s.get_char(i),i);
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

At last in the main function:

```
delete S1;
delete S2;
delete S3;
```